# Воспроизуведение url музыки

Tags: python, pygame

Как можно воспроизвести музыку, используя к примеру pygame, по ссылке?

Пример ссылки:
https://mp3minusovki.com/music/fhvndfjwserjgt/8f58cee79c35b16d1f8de40659394245/f5135242a10a5f2b7966b355846b8adb.mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете предварительно скачать используя модуль `requests`. Потом конвертировать в `io.BytesIO`. И передать в метод [`pygame.mixer.music.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) с аргументом `namehint="mp3"`, чтобы `pygame` знал какой формат.

```py
import requests
import pygame
import io

url = 'https://mp3minusovki.com/music/fhvndfjwserjgt/8f58cee79c35b16d1f8de40659394245/f5135242a10a5f2b7966b355846b8adb.mp3'
req = requests.get(url)
res = io.BytesIO(req.content)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(res, namehint="mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```